# What is the most efficient way to turn a metric formula into a metric tensor?

Tags: polynomials, differential-geometry

I have a metric formula:

```
ds=(-dt^2)*(c3+a3*t)^2+(dxC^2*(t0^2+t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4)+
   (dxM^2*(t0^2+t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4)+(dxY^2*(t0^2+t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4)
```

How do I turn this into a matrix (metric tensor)? My best attempt so far is:

```
g = {{Coefficient[ds, dt^2], 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0,Coefficient[ds, (dxC)^2], 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, Coefficient[ds, (dxM)^2], 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, Coefficient[ds, (dxY)^2]}}
```

But this seems clumsy - forcing each of the components into the matrix. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `CoefficientArrays`:

```
CoefficientArrays[ds, {dt, dxC, dxM, dxY}] // Last
% // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

First define the metric tensor `G` with unassigned values via `G=Array[g,{4,4}]`. I'll use $(-,+,+,+)$ for the metric signature, so let `dx={-dt,dxC,dxM,dxY}`. Then `Sum[G[[i, j]]*dx[[i]]*dx[[j]], {i, 4}, {j, 4}]` gives you the metric, which should be equal to `ds`.

Define the coefficients relative to `g[i,j]` or `Flatten@G` via

```
forms = Coefficient[Sum[G[[i, j]]*dx[[i]]*dx[[j]], {i, 4}, {j, 4}], Flatten@G, 1];
```

which gives you every symbolic differential form appearing in `G`. Now use `forms` with `ds` to list the components of the metric:

```
coeff = Table[Coefficient[ds, forms[[i]], 1], {i, Length@forms}];
```

and define the `g`'s via

```
MapThread[(#1 = #2) &, {Flatten@G, coeff}];
```

To check, just input `G`

```
In[7]:= G

Out[7]= {{-(c3 + a3 t)^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (t0^2 + t1^2)^2/(4 t0^4), 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, (t0^2 + t1^2)^2/(4 t0^4), 0}, {0, 0, 0, (t0^2 + t1^2)^2/(
  4 t0^4)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to replace each `dt^2` etc. in the original expression by the matrix expression for the appropriate symmetric 2-tensor.

For this we first define a list of symbols used for the 1-forms,

```
oneformsymbols = {dt, dxC, dxM, dxY};
```

and a list of corresponding vectors,

```
oneforms = IdentityMatrix[4];
```

From these we construct a list of replacement rules for the 2-tensors

```
replacementrules = Flatten[
 Table[
  oneformsymbols[[i]] oneformsymbols[[j]] -> 
   Normal@Symmetrize@TensorProduct[oneforms[[i]], oneforms[[j]]]
  ,
   {i, 4},
   {j, 1, i}
  ]
 , 1]
```

With these replacement rules in hand one can generate the matrix of metric components from the line element `ds` by

```
ds /. replacementrules
```

Note that this setup can also deal with metrics with off-diagonal elements.